# How to mitigate a bug in Rakudo with NativeCall?

Tags: c, raku, nativecall

I want to be able to use a double pointer in a class with REPR CStruct/CPointer:

```c
typedef struct CipherContext {
          void    *cipher;
    const uint8_t *key;
          size_t   key_len;
    const uint8_t *path;
          size_t   path_len;
          size_t   block_size;
          void    *handle;

          int      (*cipher_init)(void **, const uint8_t *, size_t);
          int      (*cipher_encode)(void *, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t);
          int      (*cipher_decode)(void *, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t);
          void     (*cipher_free)(void *);
    const uint8_t *(*cipher_strerror)(int);
} CipherContext;

      int            cipher_context_init(CipherContext **, const uint8_t *, size_t, const uint8_t *, size_t, size_t);
      int            cipher_context_encode(CipherContext *, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t);
      int            cipher_context_decode(CipherContext *, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t);
      void           cipher_context_free(CipherContext *);
const uint8_t       *cipher_context_strerror(int);
```

Perl 6 code:

```
method new(Blob :$key!, Str :$path!, Int :$block-size!) {
    my Pointer[::?CLASS]     $ptr     .= new;
    my Int                   $err      = cipher_context_init($ptr, $key, $key.elems, $path, $path.codes, $block-size);
    return $ptr.deref unless $err;

    my Str $errstr = cipher_context_strerror($err) || do {
        my &cipher-strerror = nativecast(:(int32 --> Str), $!cipher-strerror);
        cipher-strerror($err)
    };
    die "Failed to initialize cipher context: $errstr";
}

submethod DESTROY() {
    cipher_context_free(self)
}
```

Short golf:

```
use v6.d;
use Nativecall;

class Foo is repr('CPointer') { 
    my Pointer[::?CLASS] $foo .= nw;
}
```

Only I can't figure out how to do it due to a [bug in Rakudo](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2673). Is there a better way I could be handling errors in the C portion of the code (which is why I'm writing it like this)?

Comment: Please provide much more information. "bug in Rakudo"? What did you try? How did it fail? Also please try to avoid the impression that this is not a programming question, i.e. that it is a question on using an editor feature.

Comment: You want to use "using a double pointer in cipher_context_init and returning an int" to align code in an editor?

Comment: My bad @Yunnosch, i'll include more information

Comment: I made an issue about this. It provides much more information as to what the problem is https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2673

Comment: So the problem is a bug which you already reported to the appropriate person. What is it you want here? A workaround for a bug? Also questions on StackOverflow are expected to contain all needed information. A link is considered a weakness because of the risk that it becomes unavailable. Also all info should be in the question itself and not hidden in comments.

Comment: Sorry about the haphazardness in the question. I'm looking for a workaround for the bug

Comment: Simplify the example as much as possible.  Would a single struct member and a single function demonstrate the issue?  I'm still trying to figure out with all of that exactly what the question is.

Comment: A 'double pointer' is just a Pointer that happens to point to a Pointer.  You can usually just tell Perl 6 it is a Pointer and just make sure you set its value correctly.

Comment: Difficult to say without more detail, but perhaps `cipher_context_init()` wants a pointer to a pointer that it will then set to point to some memory it allocates for you?  You can usually do that with a `Pointer is rw`.

Comment: I was using `Pointer[::?CLASS]  is rw`. The question's been updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That fails for the same reason this fails:

```
class Foo {...}

BEGIN Foo ~~ Bool; # <------

class Foo{
}
```

Part of the problem seems to be that `Foo` isn't composed yet when the `Pointer.^parameterize` method gets called.

So it isn't a subtype of `Any` yet. (or even `Mu`)

A workaround is to add a `.^compose` call in a `BEGIN` phaser before you use `Pointer[::?﻿CLASS]`.

```
class Foo is repr('CPointer') {
  BEGIN ::?CLASS.^compose;

  my Pointer[::?CLASS] $foo .= new;
}
```

---

My guess is that the real fix will be to change the `Bool.ACCEPTS(Bool:U: \topic)` candidate to `Bool.ACCEPTS(Bool:U: Mu \topic)`.

The reason I think that is because this also fails with basically the same error:

```
Mu ~~ Bool
```